# Set condition for mass action checkbox visibility in magento

Tags: php, magento, checkbox

I have a magento module that I'm developing for importing products into magento.
I Have a grid where the user can select his products, and import them all (Mass Action).
If the user has products already imported in the list, then it's shown in the grid, but the user shouldn't select it (check it's product checkbox) to avoid re-importing the product.

My question is, how can I add a condition for a mass action checkbox visibility ?

Here is my Grid's _prepareMassaction:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('sku');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('import');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('import', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('import')->__('Import'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massImport'),
        'confirm' => Mage::helper('import')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

Any Help someone ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey buddy you can use below code for as per your requirement

```
 $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sliders');
    if (!is_array($ids)) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select items.'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($ids as $id) {
                $model = Mage::getSingleton('sliders/sliders')->load($id);
                $model->delete();
            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) have been deleted.', count($ids))
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('contact')->__('An error occurred while mass deleting contacts. Please review log and try again.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
```

Comment: This code ins't intended for what I was looking for, besides, it's for some action after the row selection (check it's checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to 'hide' the checkboxes you want, but you can pre-select the checkboxes (the ones not previously imported yet, in your case)

To do this, add this in Grid.php:

```
protected $_massactionBlockName = 'yourmodule/adminhtml_index_grid_massaction';
```

Then create a new file in .../Block/Adminhtml/Index/Grid/Massaction.php with following code:

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Block_Adminhtml_Index_Grid_Massaction extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction
{

    public function getSelectedJson()
    {
        //$gridIds = $this->getParentBlock()->getCollection()->getAllIds();
        $gridIds = getTheIdsYouWantHere();
        if(!empty($gridIds)) {
            return join(",", $gridIds);
        }
        return '';
    }

}
```